# How can I get rid of the /* I see at the end of every PDF I generate?

Tags: mpdf

I'm using mPDF to generate PDFs of webpage content. I've noticed that at the end of every PDF I generate I am seeing a `/*`.  Pretty Weird.  I am using mPDF with Wordpress. I suspect that maybe there is something with my template possibly that is causing the issue.

I tried the example first pdf code and that did not produce the `/*`.

My settings for mPDF look like this:

```
$url = urldecode($_REQUEST['url']);
$title = urldecode($_REQUEST['title']);

// For $_POST i.e. forms with fields
if (count($_POST) > 0) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

    foreach($_POST as $name => $post) {
      $formvars = array($name => $post . " \n");
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formvars);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

} elseif (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

} else {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}


/* for debug */
var_dump($html); die;

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'format' => 'Letter',
    'margin_left' => 0,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_top' => 6,
    'margin_bottom' => 6,
    'margin_header' => 5,
    'margin_footer' => 5
]);

$mpdf->useSubstitutions = false; // optional - just as an example
$mpdf->simpleTables = true;
// $mpdf->SetHeader($url . "\n\n");  // optional - just as an example
$mpdf->CSSselectMedia='mpdf'; // assuming you used this in the document header
$mpdf->SetAuthor("author");
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->setBasePath($url);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($title . ".pdf", 'D');
```

I am submitting a page URL from a form to my createPDF.php page and using curl to get the content of the page.  Is there something special I need to do here to clean the content?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and include the code you are using to scrape a site to generate the PDF. You should also probably `var_dump` the data returned from the scraped site. If the mysterious `/*` isn't in your code it is probably coming from the scraped site.

Comment: @Dave I just tried what you suggested. I var_dump my $html var and here is what i saw. Just before the </body></html> there is a double quotation mark and some space.  Could wp_footer() being creating that text?

Comment: I resolved this issue.  When I enabled gzip compression then I started seeing a script tag at the end of the pdfs.  I removed that by running a preg_replace on the $html to clean it.  Now, I am seeing an extra blank page on most pdfs I create.